# Positioning the PlotLabel above the Frame

Tags: plotting, frame

For the plot below, there is a gap between the `PlotLabel` and the `Frame`. How can this gap be reduced so as to position the `PlotLabel` just above the `Frame`?

```
LogPlot[{x^2}
 , {x, -8, 8}
 , PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Blue, Red}
 , FrameLabel -> {Style["X", 16, Black], Style["Y", 20, Black]}
 , PlotLabel -> 
  Style["a^+=1, b^+=1", 20, Blue, Bold, 
   FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman Unslanted"]
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]]
 , ImageSize -> 700
 , FrameTicks -> {
   {{{100, "", {0.02, 0}}, {10, "10", {0.020, 0}}, {1, 
      "1", {0.02, 0}}, {0.1, "0.1", {0.02, 0}}}, {{100, 
      "", {0.02, 0}}, {10, "", {0.020, 0}}, {1, "", {0.02, 0}}, {0.1, 
      "", {0.02, 0}}}}, {{{10, "10", {0.024, 0}}, {5, 
      "5", {0.024, 0}}, {0, "0", {0.024, 0}}, {-10, 
      "-10", {0.024, 0}}, {-5, "-5", {0.024, 0}}}, {{10, 
      "", {0.024, 0}}, {5, "", {0.024, 0}}, {0, "", {0.024, 0}}, {-10,
       "", {0.024, 0}}, {-5, "", {0.024, 0}}}}
   }
 , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 23]
 ]
```

Comment: ImagePadding->{{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}

Comment: @I.M. , It worked. Thank you.